# How can I alternate between even and odd numbers?

Tags: perl

I want the output to show which numbers are even and which are odd. Strangely, I only get `100 is odd` 100 times. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```
my @zahlen = (1..100);
my $zahlen = @zahlen;

foreach (@zahlen){
    if (@zahlen % 2) {
        print "$zahlen is even\n";
    } else {
        print "$zahlen is odd\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: In the expression `if (@zahlen % 2)`, `@zahlen` is the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong variables in the wrong places.  You set `$zahlen` to a constant value outside the loop (100).  You can use it as the loop iterator variable instead.

Also, you should use the scalar `$zahlen` instead of the array `@zahlen` in the `if` statement.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @zahlen = (1 .. 10);

foreach my $zahlen (@zahlen) {
    if ($zahlen % 2) {
        print "$zahlen is odd\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$zahlen is even\n";
    }
}
```

Prints (I changed 100 to 10 to simplify the output):

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```

Answer (score 0):

The code can be written in alternative more concise form

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @zahlen = (1 .. 10);

say "$_ is " . (($_ % 2) ? "odd" : "even") for @zahlen;
```

Output

```
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```